# Key ... is not present in table "". on postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

Tengo un servidor montado con Flask y está conectada a una BD en Postgresql.
En mi base de datos tengo 2 tablas que están conectadas(FK).

En la tabla 1, están guardados todos los dispositivos que tengo conectados. 
En la tabla 2, tengo todos los registros de los dispositivos de la tabla 1. Aquí me llega información de estos cada 15 min.

El problema es que en muchas ocasiones se instalan nuevos dispositivos, y estos se agregan automáticamente al JSON que se recibe y procesa en mi server. Entonces cuando el server intenta hacer el insert, marca el error que no se puede agregar el valor en la tabla 2 porque no está registrado en la tabla 1.

¿Existe una manera de que cuando se reciba el error, se cree el dispositivo en la tabla 1 con valores por default? (los valores se actualizarían después)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es no esperar a que surja el error sino que antes de insertar en la tabla2, verificar en la tabla1 si existe y si no insertarlo.